# GCP Logs Explorer Query for creation of asset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I am searching whether Log Explorer will give any response if an asset is created in my GCP project like if I create a VM Instance. will I see that response in log explorer. If so can I have a query where I can get if an instance is created?

Answer (score 2):

Google cloud records events that create (insert), modify and delete resources. These logs are kept for 30 days, but this is changeable for longer time periods.

For example, to search the logs for events that created a Compute Engine VM instance using the CLI:

```
gcloud logging read 'protoPayload.methodName:"compute.instances.insert"' \
--project=GCP_PROJECT_ID \
--format=json
```

In Logs Explorer, enter this string in the filter bar:

```
protoPayload.methodName:"compute.instances.insert"
```

[Cloud Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit)